# How to write a Numbered List of Text in a specific location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, aspose, aspose.words

I need to write an array of string to a numbered list but in a specific location of a document.

For example, the array is:

```
sentence[0] : Jonathan Spielberg
sentence[1] : Stephanie Black
sentence[2] : Marcus Smith
sentence[3] : Kylie Ashton
...
```

Then it should be written in a specific location, let's say under the section heading "A. Candidate's Name"

```
A. Candidate's Name
     1.  Jonathan Spielberg
     2.  Stephanie Black
     3.  Marcus Smith
     4.  Kylie Ashton
```

My logic so far is using a unique tags, then it will be replaced and looped by the array to be written on a numbered list. Let's say the unique tag is `######CANDIDATESNAME#####`. I've done such way, but that doesn't work.

How am I supposed to do to code this?

P.S. : I have a template document .doc/.docx for the only section headings, then I just need to fill it with the numbered list.

Comment: loop through elements and use <li> tag. Also put your code what exactly you are writing...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you following solution.

1) Implement IReplacingCallback interface.
2) Use Range.Replace method to find the unique tag.
3) [Move the cursor](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Using+DocumentBuilder+to+Modify+a+Document+Easily#UsingDocumentBuildertoModifyaDocumentEasily-MovingtheCursor) to the text (unique tag) and insert the numbered list.

Please read following documentation link and use following code to insert numbered list at the position of unique tag.

[Find and Replace](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Find+and+Replace)

```
string[] list = new string[] { "Jonathan Spielberg", "Stephanie Black", "Marcus Smith", "Kylie Ashton" };

Document mainDoc = new Document(MyDir + "in.docx");
mainDoc.Range.Replace(new Regex("######CANDIDATESNAME#####"), new FindandInsertList(list), false);
mainDoc.Save(MyDir + " Out.docx");
//--------------------------------------
public class FindandInsertList : IReplacingCallback
{
    private string[] listitems;

    public FindandInsertList(string[] list)
    {
        listitems = list;
    }

    ReplaceAction IReplacingCallback.Replacing(ReplacingArgs e)
    {
        // This is a Run node that contains either the beginning or the complete match.
        Node currentNode = e.MatchNode;

        // The first (and may be the only) run can contain text before the match,
        // in this case it is necessary to split the run.
        if (e.MatchOffset > 0)
            currentNode = SplitRun((Run)currentNode, e.MatchOffset);

        // This array is used to store all nodes of the match for further removing.
        ArrayList runs = new ArrayList();

        // Find all runs that contain parts of the match string.
        int remainingLength = e.Match.Value.Length;
        while (
            (remainingLength > 0) &&
            (currentNode != null) &&
            (currentNode.GetText().Length <= remainingLength))
        {
            runs.Add(currentNode);
            remainingLength = remainingLength - currentNode.GetText().Length;

            // Select the next Run node.
            // Have to loop because there could be other nodes such as BookmarkStart etc.
            do
            {
                currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling;
            }
            while ((currentNode != null) && (currentNode.NodeType != NodeType.Run));
        }

        // Split the last run that contains the match if there is any text left.
        if ((currentNode != null) && (remainingLength > 0))
        {
            SplitRun((Run)currentNode, remainingLength);
            runs.Add(currentNode);
        }

        // Create Document Buidler
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(e.MatchNode.Document as Document);

        builder.MoveTo((Run)runs[runs.Count - 1]);

        builder.ListFormat.List = e.MatchNode.Document.Lists.Add(ListTemplate.NumberDefault);


        foreach (string item in listitems)
        {
            builder.Writeln(item);
        }

        // End the bulleted list.
        builder.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers();

        // Now remove all runs in the sequence.
        foreach (Run run in runs)
            run.Remove();

        // Signal to the replace engine to do nothing because we have already done all what we wanted.
        return ReplaceAction.Skip;
    }

    private static Run SplitRun(Run run, int position)
    {
        Run afterRun = (Run)run.Clone(true);
        afterRun.Text = run.Text.Substring(position);
        run.Text = run.Text.Substring(0, position);
        run.ParentNode.InsertAfter(afterRun, run);
        return afterRun;
    }
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.